# OkHttpClient doesn't work for "http" urls ("http://www.example.com") but works for "https" urls ("https://www.example.com")

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, android-networking

This code runs the `onFailure` function.

```
OkHttpClient client;
client = new OkHttpClient();
```

*here the url is a **http** url.*

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://www.example.com").build();
```

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                textView.setText("Failed to get response");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(myResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

but when url is a **https** url like
`Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://www.example.com").build();`
then `onResponse` is called.

How can make this work for `http` websites. The website I need this to work on is a `http` only website.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/2444099

Comment: The link has the relevant information. It worked.